# How to upload large files with multipart form in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload two images (10MB and 1MB size) in a *POST* method with multipart form. 
Using **Alamofire** upload method this way.

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
multipartFormData.append(InputStream(data: imageMedia.data), // 10MB data
                         withLength: UInt64(imageMedia.data.count),
                         name: imageMedia.type.rawValue,
                         fileName: imageMedia.filename,
                         mimeType: imageMedia.mimeType)

multipartFormData.append(InputStream(data: maskMedia.data), // 1MB data
                         withLength: UInt64(maskMedia.data.count),
                         name: maskMedia.type.rawValue,
                         fileName: maskMedia.filename,
                         mimeType: maskMedia.mimeType)
}, with: request).responseData { afDataResponse in
    switch afDataResponse.result {
    case .success(let data):
        completion(data)
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error with alamofire response \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

It goes into the failure and prints:

> error with alamofire response: URLSessionTask failed with error: The
> operation couldn’t be completed. Message too long

Same *POST* request on Postman works fine so it's not a server issue.
What is a solution to this?

EDIT:
With smaller images (5MB and 1MB) everything works fine.

**EDIT 2**:
This is the *error*:

> sessionTaskFailed(error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=40
> "Message too long"
> UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask
> <8F7404DD-2947-4B18-9F23-C23F0483F440>.<1>,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x600001068280 [0x1b9553c60]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
> 0x100201bbd8ef26350000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=40,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalUploadTask <8F7404DD-2947-4B18-9F23-C23F0483F440>.<1>" )})

Comment: What's the output of `error` and not only `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: Do you have a firewall/VPN? Some says that it could be them that limit the size.

Comment: No firewall or VPN. I just discovered that it's an issue only on iOS simulator. Working good on device

Answer (score 0):

try this to upload all size of images or videos

```
    func upload(){
       let URL = "\(Constants.baseURL)\(path)"
       let _headers : HTTPHeaders = ["lang" : "language".localized(),"Content-Type": "application/json","jwt" : AuthManager.authKey()]
     var params : [String : Any] = [:]
     AF.upload(multipartFormData: { [self] (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
        }
        let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        multipartFormData.append(self.VideoFileData, withName: "url", fileName:  "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
        
    }, to: URL, method: .post, headers: _headers).responseJSON{ [self] (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let upload):
                do {
                    self.loadingView.hide()
                    let Lists = try JSONDecoder().decode(StoreDataVideoModel.self, from: response.data!)
                    print(Lists)
                    if(Lists.status == 200){
                        
                    }else{
                        
                    }
                } catch let error{
                    self.requestStatus(code: -1, Msg: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                if response.error != nil{
                    self.requestStatus(code: -1, Msg: "\(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    return
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("wrong")
                self.requestStatus(code: -1, Msg: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }.uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
        //Current upload progress of file
        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    })
}
```